# Trouble using regex to locate special characters

Tags: python, regex

I am using beautifulsoup and selenium to collect some data from a page. After narrowing the data down the string that I want, it gives me 'First Blood○○○○○●○○○○'. My goal is to determine the position of the filled in dot (so 5 in this case if we are counting from 0).

I started by trying to remove all of the non-special characters using:

```
test = re.sub(r'[a-z]+', '', collectStatistics[5], re.I)
```

Which gave me 'F B○○○○○●○○○○' so I am guessing F B are also special characters. I have no clue how to go about writing a regex that will detect the filled in circle so any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think regexes <s>(regices?)</s> are overkill here.

First, cut off everything after the filled dot:

```
line = line.split('●')[0] # Split on filled dots, then take only the first part
```

Now, count the empty dots:

```
result = line.count('○') # Count occurrences
```

Comment: This worked great thanks! Definitely didn't even consider this option but its so much simpler than I thought it was

Answer (score 0):

It founds `F` and `B` because your regex finds lowercase letters.If you want to find all of them change regex to `[a-zA-Z]+`

```
import re
collectStatistics = "First Blood○○○○○●○○○○"
test = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]+', '', collectStatistics,re.I)
print (test)
```

OUTPUT :

```
 ○○○○○●○○○○
```